# I'm going through shopping cart nightmares!

Tags: ecommerce, shopping-cart

Help Please! My situation is that I need a stand alone cart that has robust DB functions which will not only collect all data relative to the purchase, but then either allow me to export all of that information to QuickBooks or convey all data relative to the purchase to Paypal so that I can integrate those records with QuickBooks. Either will do! But it has to be a robust database!  My bookkeeper is QuickBooks proficient and finally my accounting is in a beautiful and highly functional format. But my cart stinks!  Every single sales record must be hand entered into QBs! Cool Cart, my present cart,  not only cannot convey the information it collects to Paypal, but it can't integrate to QuickBooks either and the owner has no interest in doing anything to help or for that matter offer any tech support!

Paypal's cart, my first cart, kept the inventory and sales records in a format that QuickBooks loves, but it is so incomplete when it comes to a company needing a robust cart capable of offering coupons, wholesale pricing for retailers, many other customer option shortcomings.

I'm going down the tubes trying to research 100+ cars on line only to find out that they may have a DB but the DB won't either integrate with Paypal or Quick Books or it won't collect all of the sales data, down to the little details, eg. what item exactly did the customer buy, how much did that customer pay for that item, was a record of sales tax collected or the shipping costs recorded in the DB?  I don't want or need the actual Credit card information! I just need complete data to integrate to my bookkeeping systems. Otherwise, I am relegated to huge time consuming data entry by hand!

I just need a highly functioning cart not the hosting.   Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried shopify, real simple to get going and has quickbooks intergration http://www.shopify.com/blog/3032962-bookkeeping-made-easier-with-quickify